# How to acess private function from another function

Tags: typescript

I am receiving an error while trying to access a private function inside another function

```
class GameController {
  public async cardShuffle (req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
      other code here...

      const treatment = this.cardTreatment(shuffledCards)

      console.log(treatment)
    })
  }

  private cardTreatment (cards: Array<String | Number>): Array<String | Number> {
    return cards
  }
}

export default new GameController()
```

Error:

> (node:2645) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cardTreatment' of undefined

Comment: Did you search this site or do a Google search for *Cannot read property of undefined*? This sort of question has been asked (and answered) dozens of times here before; one of them should certainly point you in the right direction to solve this problem yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is not that the function is private, but that `this` is `undefined` in the context you called it.  For example, you may have done `const shuffle = controller.cardShuffle;  shuffle()`.

See below:

```js
class Example {
    foo() {
        return this.bar();
    }
    bar() {
        return 'It works!';
    }
}

const test = new Example();

console.log(test.foo())

const foo = test.foo;

try {
    console.log(foo())
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Doesnt work');
}

console.log(foo.call(test))
```